# When I delete or add any item in Gridview , it is done successfully But when I close the application .. Do not save anything you did in the past

Tags: android, arraylist

i'm use CustomGridView in ArrayList >>
When I delete or add any item, it is done successfully
But when I close the application , Do not save anything you did in the past , I want to save what is happening in the application from the delete or add in case the application is closed

https://1.top4top.net/p_13160kom81.png

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

```
    GridView gridView;
//SharedPreferences shared;
ArrayList<Item> gridArray = new ArrayList<>() ;
CustomGridViewAdapter customGridAdapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);



    final Bitmap homeIcon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.getResources(), R.drawable.home);
    final Bitmap userIcon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.getResources(), R.drawable.personal);

    gridArray.add(new Item(homeIcon,"Home"));
    gridArray.add(new Item(userIcon,"User"));
    gridArray.add(new Item(homeIcon,"House"));
    gridArray.add(new Item(userIcon,"Friend"));
    gridArray.add(new Item(homeIcon,"Home"));
    gridArray.add(new Item(userIcon,"Personal"));
    gridArray.add(new Item(homeIcon,"Home"));
    gridArray.add(new Item(userIcon,"User"));
    gridArray.add(new Item(homeIcon,"Building"));
    gridArray.add(new Item(userIcon,"User"));
    gridArray.add(new Item(homeIcon,"Home"));
    gridArray.add(new Item(userIcon,"xyz"));


    gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridView1);
    final Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn);
    Button btn_d = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_d);

    customGridAdapter = new CustomGridViewAdapter(this, R.layout.row_grid, gridArray);
    gridView.setAdapter(customGridAdapter);



    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            gridArray.add(new Item(userIcon,"E_item"));

            customGridAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "add Done", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

    btn_d.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            gridArray.remove(3);
            customGridAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "remove  Done", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    });


    gridView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener()
    {

        public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View v, int position, long arg3)
        {
            gridArray.remove(position);
            customGridAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

            String a = String.valueOf(position);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), a, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return false;
        }

    });

}



}
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to use any storage (DB,SharedPreferences,remote) to do the Persistance. Currently whenever you relaunch your activity you are resetting your arrayList again with all items.